# where to keep frequently used methods in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to implement MVC architecture in my company, So can anyone suggest where to keep frequently used methods to call on all pages. Like:

states ddl, departments ddl  also roles list and etc...

Please give me suggestions where to keep them in architecture.

Thanks

Comment: Base controller is the place

Comment: Do you think viewmodel is the ideal place to keep them?

Comment: you could just create classes with those methods and then use dependency injection to inject them into your controller. That'll help you with making your overall design more unit testable.

Comment: Do you have any examples i can take a look at to use dependency injection? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different solutions depending on the scale of your application. For small projects, you can simply create a set of classes in MVC application itself. Just create a Utils folder and a DropDownLists class and away you go. For simple stuff like this, I find it's acceptable to have static methods that return the data, lists, or enumerations you require.

Another option is to create an abstract MyControllerBase class that descends from Controller and put your cross-cutting concerns in there, perhaps as virtual methods or properties. Then all your actual controllers can descend from MyControllerBase.

For larger applications, or in situations where you might share these classes with other MVC applications, create a shared library such as MySolution.Utils and reference the library from all projects as required.

Yet another possibility for larger solutions is to use Dependency Injection to inject the requirements in at runtime. You might consider using something like Unity or Ninject for this task.

Example, as per your request ([also in GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/simongoldstone/7215735))

```
// declare these in a shared library
public interface ILookupDataProvider
{
    IEnumerable<string> States { get; }
} 

public class LookupDataProvider: ILookupDataProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<string> States
    {
        get
        {
            return new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
        }
    }
}

// then inject the requirement in to your controller
// in this example, the [Dependency] attribute comes from Unity (other DI containers are available!)
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Dependency]
    public ILookupDataProvider LookupDataProvider { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myModel = new MyModel
        {
            States = LookupDataProvider.States
        };

        return View(myModel);
    }
}
```

In the code above, you'll need to configure your Dependency Injection technology but this is definitely outside the scope of the answer (check SO for help here). Once configured correctly, the concrete implementation of ILookupDataProvider will be injected in at runtime to provide the data.

One final solution I would suggest, albeit this would be very much overkill for small projects would be to host shared services in a WCF service layer. This allows parts of your application to be separated out in to highly-scalable services, should the need arise in the future.

Comment: My approach has been to put together various "helper" and "support" class libraries, organized by functional area.

Comment: Do you have any examples that uses dependency injection?

Comment: It's not something that could be described in a few lines. There are hundreds of choices and technologies available. I'll see if I can dig out some good example articles for you to read...

Comment: @SimonGoldstone I am getting null value in 'LookupDataProvider.States'

Comment: Did you install Unity (or other DI container?) Have you configured it? Did you include the [Dependency] Attribute?

Comment: I went through lot of source online to figure out how to configure the Unity DI into my application. I was able to download and include the Microsoft.Practices.unity.dll that is all. I am all new to this DI thing and trying to learn. Can you please guide me how to install this Unity DI into my application. Thanks

Comment: You're outside the scope of this question now. And I don't think that StackOverflow is the right place for you to get a tutorial on Unity either. Plus, there are a number of config scenarios for Unity. You need to read some tutorials, such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650806.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203208.aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488308/UsingplusUnityplusforplusIoCplusandplusDI, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649614.aspx,  etc.

Comment: One other comment... Unity is just one implementation of a DI container. There are literally dozens. I like Ninject too - research them all and pick the one that you think has the best documentation, support, forums, etc.